# getting property of a class object variable c#

Tags: c#

I need to Assign a value to a Variable of one class by its name as string.

that is,

i have a class,

```
public class Test
{
    public int a = 0; //{ get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
}
```

Here, i can set the value to the Test Variables like,

```
Test test = new Test();
string var1= "b";
// By Using Reflection
PropertyInfo pi= test.GetType().GetProperty(var1);
pi.SetValue(test, Convert.ChangeType(1,pi.PropertyType), null);
```

so i can get test.b as 1.
Likewise i need to set the value for a. How do i accomplish it.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Why do you need reflection when you have the instance of test as well as a public field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `int a` isn't a property, it is a field. Hence, you have to get the `FieldInfo` using `GetField` instead of `GetProperty`:

```
FieldInfo fi= test.GetType().GetField(var1);
fi.SetValue(test, Convert.ChangeType(1,fi.FieldType));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its worked out. Is there any option to find object Info same as FieldInfo.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is not a property, but a field. You can get it almost the same way, but using other reflection facilities.

```
FieldInfo a = test.GetType().GetField("a");
int result = (int)a.GetValue(test);
```